# Identify a short story where a husband purposely drives his wife crazy

Tags: identification-request

When I was in college I read a short story for a class and I'd like to find it again. I'm recalling this from my bad memory, so there could be many errors here..

The general plot was that a husband purposely tricks his wife into thinking she's crazy, and eventually has her committed to an asylum. I thought I remembered the professor explaining that this book was the original "Psycho", not the movie version.

Throughout the story the husband does things like order pizzas to be delivered to the house while he's out, so his wife would think she did it. Or maybe it was a refrigerator or something. I also remember something about a mask..

Eventually the wife starts to think she's losing her mind, then the police somehow get involved, and the wife is committed to an asylum.

Comment: When were you in college? Where was that college located? What class was this for?

Comment: Sounds a bit like 'Gaslight', but that's a film based on a play, and set long before 'ordering pizza' was a thing!

Comment: Came here to make the same comment as Kate Bunting. [Play](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gas_Light), [film](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaslight_(1944_film)), but I couldn't find any mention of a short story version. Maybe something inspired by that?

Comment: You might page through https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Gaslighting/Literature (I've been trying, but I have a toddler "helping").

Comment: I could totally have it wrong about ordering pizza! I think the story was set in the 50's.. I went to college in early 2000s and I guess this was an english class. Maybe he didn't order pizza, maybe it was appliances or something.. I just can't quite remember :(

Comment: I agree this does sound a LOT like @KateBunting's suggestion - Gas Light.. but I obviously have a lot of the plot and details wrong. I guess my memory really screwed this story up! In my memory, the husband succeeds in getting the wife to think she's gone crazy, and everyone else thinks she went crazy too. It wasn't a happy ending.